# Running proxy service inside docker containers

Tags: docker, proxy, docker-compose, docker-container

I am using luminati proxy for a service ,I need to run luminati command to instantiate proxy server and then run the script,It works fine on my local machine

I need to reproduce this behaviour on docker container
This is relevant part of my docker file

```
RUN npm install -g @luminati-io/luminati-proxy --unsafe-perm
RUN luminati --daemon
COPY . /scrape_l
WORKDIR /scrape_l
ENTRYPOINT celery -A current_profile.tasks worker --loglevel=info
```

whenever I send a request it gives me "Connection reset by peer Error 104"

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert in luminati, but based on my understanding of docker you may have to expose ports on which various luminati services are listening, in your Dockerfile e.g.

```
EXPOSE 22999 22999 #for Proxy manager 
EXPOSE 22555 22555 #for dropin 
EXPOSE 24000 24000 #for first configurable proxy
```